# Jquery not selector returning everything

Tags: jquery

I was implementing a dropdown menu. I want to hide the menu if clicked elsewhere. I tried using jquery .not, but i observed

```
$('div').not('.nav-toggle').hide()
```

Hides all including div with class nav-toggle. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. One line of code isn't enough for us to help.

Comment: Are you sure that the `.nav-toggle` element isn't contained within a `div`? It's likely that its parent is being hidden, which means it would get hidden as well.

Comment: Your code should hide any `div` that don't have the class `.nav-toggle`, not if it contains a child with it... This should do the trick: `$('.nav-toggle').hide();` or if the element is attached later, then: `$(document).find('.nav-toggle', function(){ $(this).hide()});` if you only have one menu...

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL That's the opposite of what he wants. He wants to hide everything *except* `.nav-toggle`.

Comment: @Barmar " I want to hide the menu if clicked elsewhere." I believe he wants to hide the menu.

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL I think `.nav-toggle` is not the menu, he wants to keep that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike McCaughan's comment is probably right. You have container DIVs that are also being hidden by this.

You should give all the DIVs that you want to hide a common class, which I call `newclass` below. Then you can do:

```
$('.newclass:not(.nav-toggle)').hide();
```

This hides all the `.newclass` elements except the ones that are also `.nav-toggle`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should hide any div that don't have the class .nav-toggle...

This should do the trick:

```
$('.nav-toggle').hide();
```

or if the element is attached later to the DOM, then:

```
$(document).find('.nav-toggle', function(){ 
     $(this).hide();
});
```

if you only have one, if you have more than one element

```
$('.nav-toggle').each(function(){ 
     $(this).hide();
});
```

or

```
$(document).find('.nav-toggle').each(function(){ 
     $(this).hide();
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why does it matter when it's attached to the DOM? There's no difference between `$(document).find(selector)` and `$(selector)`.

Comment: You don't need `.each` -- modification functions like `.hide()` automatically work on all matching elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).click(function() {
  $('.nav-toggle').hide() 
});

$(".menu_show").click(function(e) {
  $('.nav-toggle').show() 
  e.stopPropagation(); 
  return false;                  
});
```